# How to programmatically import JSON into MongoDB via node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have a large nested object defined as a single document from a mobile app that I want to backup to MongoDB via an Express-powered REST API.  This is not something that will be done often or in real time, so I don't need to build a full transactional API, I'd rather just backup and restore as a single action if possible.

Doing this on the command line is simple, but I'd like to build a REST API to do this programmatically.  Example command line:

```
mongoimport --db workouttest --collection workouts --file workouts.json --jsonArray
```

[Sample JSON](http://pastebin.com/7btb4A4H) used in the mongoimport example above, defined by the following schema:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var workoutSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    startDate: Date,
    userProfile: {
        age: Number,
        name: String,
        bodyWeight: Number
    },
    program: [{
        name: String,
        goal: Number,
        notes: String,
        workoutDiary: [{
            date: Date,
            sets: [{
                repCount: Number,
                weight: Number
            }]
        }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution on windows:-**

**Step 1:**
**Create a bat file**

File name : "myimport.bat"

```
cd D:\workspaces\mongodb_node
mongoimport -d localhost -c workouts < workouts.json
echo "completed...."
exit /b 0
```

**Step 2:**

Please ensure to change the database name and bat file name accordingly

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, Server = require('mongodb').Server, ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers, ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID, Binary = require('mongodb').Binary, GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore, Grid = require('mongodb').Grid, Code = require('mongodb').Code,
assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('localhost', new Server('localhost', 27017));

db.open(function(err, db) {
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'myimport.bat']);
bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log("Commands ...");
        });

        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        exec('myimport.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err);             
              }
              console.log("Executing ...");
            });
});
```